# What does this define mean? #define ASSERT(exp)

Tags: c

I see this code in a C program but i don't understand.

```
#define ASSERT(exp) if(!(exp)){PutStr("Err\n");}
```

Please explain and show me how to use it.
Thank you!

Comment: That's kind of a crappy `ASSERT` macro. Most `ASSERT` macros have the decency to report the file, line, and sometimes failing expression.

Comment: For the record, there is a standard macro `assert` in assert.h, which should be used instead, for all runtime asserts.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Preprocessor directives](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) in C.

Here we are creating a macro, which gets replaced during compile time with the value which we used to define the macro with.

For eg:

We can use

```
Assert(<some condition or expression>)
```

through out your code instead of

```
 if(<some condition or expression>)
 {
    putStr("Err\n");
 }
```

During compile time, compiler replaces all this Assert with the actual condition.

Answer (score 0):

Firest  It is better to change the marco name , like `MYASSERT`

Then we have:`#define MYASSERT(exp) if(!(exp))  {PutStr("Err\n");}`

Just think when I malloc a char array , I can use it :

```
char * mem = malloc(800);
MYASSERT(mem);
```

It is the same as:

```
char *mem = malloc(800);
if(!mem)
  {PutStr("Err\n");}  //well I think you already define PutStr function
```